# Cannot find the SetCount method of QueryRequest in DynamoDb with Java

Tags: java, android, count, amazon-dynamodb

In my Android app, I use DynamoDb. I want to use a query request, which returns only amount of matching items. In documentation of Amazon I found this line:

**In a request, set the Count parameter to true if you want DynamoDB to provide the total number of items that match the filter expression, instead of a list of the matching items.**

But I cannot find the SetCount method in Java. Can any body help me?

Comment: I've just found the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just found the answer. It's not SetCount as .NET .

```
QueryRequest request = new QueryRequest();
    request.setSelect(Select.COUNT);
```